# Can't establish a connection when looping over a list of urls

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to loop over a list of urls and print the status code using requests

This is my code

```
import requests

file = open("urls.txt", "r+")

for urls in file:
    list = "https://" + urls
    r = requests.get(list)
    print(r.status_code)
```

This is my urls.txt

```
login.spotify.com
hrblog.spotify.com
lon.spotify.com
cms-change.spotify.com
upgrade.spotify.com
mydata.spotify.com
spclient.wg.spotify.com
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.spotify.com%0a', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03141A30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Comment: when python reads line from file then it keeps `\n` at the end of line and you have to remove it. ie. `urls = urls.strip()`. BTW: `\n` has hex code `0a` and you can see it in your url `host='login.spotify.com%0a'`

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend using a `requests.Session` object. You should also handle the file object using a context manager.

Comment: The strip works but now when a site doesn't exist I still get the error (when the webpage doesn't exist or I get a 404 error from google)

Comment: now you have different problem and you should write new question.

Comment: if page doesn't exist then it is normal that you get error - use `try/except` to catch this error.

Answer (score 0):

When you read lines from file you have to remove `\n` from the end of line ie.

```
urls = urls.strip()
```

---

**BTW:** `\n` has hex code `0a` and you can see it in your url `host='login.spotify.com%0a'`